# How to use left join yii2

Tags: yii2

I have this code in yii 1

```html
$criteria->join = 'left join item_attr_val v ON i.item_id=t.id';
$values = array();
                    foreach ($feature as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value == '1')
                            $values [] = $key;
                    }
$criteria->compare('i.attr_value_id', $values);
```

how can I use in yii2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `leftjoin`.

e.g

```
$query = ModelName::find();
$query->leftJoin('item_attr_val', "tableName.item_id = tableName2.id");
```

Comment: I get an error -     Not unique table/alias: 'item_attr_val'

Comment: you can use this as `$query->leftJoin('item_attr_val iav', "iav.item_id = tableName2.id");`

Answer (score 1):

You Try this One...

```
$query = Model::find();
$query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'item_attr_val', "item_id = id");
```